# Ignore NA in vector sum

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, na

I want to know if is there a way to handle NA values when I try to sum some columns from a data frame?

This is a simulated example of the data I am working with:

```
id<-rep(1:4,each=8)
v1<-c(1,2,5,4,58,6,4,9)
v2<-c(78,85,56,47,12,3,65,98)
v3<-c(101,NA,452,NA,NA,45,7,56)
data<-data.frame(id,v1,v2,v3)
data
  id v1 v2  v3
1  1  1 78 101
2  1  2 85  NA
3  2  5 56 452
4  2  4 47  NA
5  3 58 12  NA
6  3  6  3  45
7  4  4 65   7
8  4  9 98  56
```

I wanto apply this formula using v1,v2,v3:

```
data$cat<-v1*0.05+v2*0.05+v3*0.05
```

This is the result I get when I use the sum:

```
data
  id v1 v2  v3   cat
1  1  1 78 101  9.00
2  1  2 85  NA    NA
3  2  5 56 452 25.65
4  2  4 47  NA    NA
5  3 58 12  NA    NA
6  3  6  3  45  2.70
7  4  4 65   7  3.80
8  4  9 98  56  8.15
```

v1,v2 and v3 are numeric vectors

Comment: Use `rowSums` with `na.rm = TRUE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `rowSums` with `na.rm = TRUE` (as @akrun said in the comment) like below

```
data$cat <- rowSums(data[-1] * c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05)[col(data[-1])], na.rm = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
> data
   id v1 v2  v3   cat
1   1  1 78 101  9.00
2   1  2 85  NA  4.35
3   1  5 56 452 25.65
4   1  4 47  NA  2.55
5   1 58 12  NA  3.50
6   1  6  3  45  2.70
7   1  4 65   7  3.80
8   1  9 98  56  8.15
9   2  1 78 101  9.00
10  2  2 85  NA  4.35
11  2  5 56 452 25.65
12  2  4 47  NA  2.55
13  2 58 12  NA  3.50
14  2  6  3  45  2.70
15  2  4 65   7  3.80
16  2  9 98  56  8.15
17  3  1 78 101  9.00
18  3  2 85  NA  4.35
19  3  5 56 452 25.65
20  3  4 47  NA  2.55
21  3 58 12  NA  3.50
22  3  6  3  45  2.70
23  3  4 65   7  3.80
24  3  9 98  56  8.15
25  4  1 78 101  9.00
26  4  2 85  NA  4.35
27  4  5 56 452 25.65
28  4  4 47  NA  2.55
29  4 58 12  NA  3.50
30  4  6  3  45  2.70
31  4  4 65   7  3.80
32  4  9 98  56  8.15
```

Comment: In case I have may other variables in the data frame, can I select only the ones I want to use in the sum?

Comment: Yes, you can specify the columns rather than `-1` in my code.

Answer (score 2):

For calculation purpose you can turn `NA` to 0.

```
data$cat <- with(replace(data, is.na(data), 0), v1*0.05 + v2*0.05 + v3*0.05)
data

#   id v1 v2  v3   cat
#1   1  1 78 101  9.00
#2   1  2 85  NA  4.35
#3   1  5 56 452 25.65
#4   1  4 47  NA  2.55
#5   1 58 12  NA  3.50
#6   1  6  3  45  2.70
#7   1  4 65   7  3.80
#8   1  9 98  56  8.15
#9   2  1 78 101  9.00
#10  2  2 85  NA  4.35
#11  2  5 56 452 25.65
#12  2  4 47  NA  2.55
#13  2 58 12  NA  3.50
#14  2  6  3  45  2.70
#15  2  4 65   7  3.80
#...
#...
```

Comment: In this case, how can I specify to apply the replace function only to certain columns in a dataframe?

Comment: Why would that matter? `replace(data, is.na(data), 0)` does not change your original dataframe i.e `data`. `data` remains as it is.

Comment: Ok. I thought my dataframe will change with the replace command but with your example I see it doesn't change. I didn't understood that completely. Thanks